# Issue when select id by BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-2.7, xml-parsing, css-selectors, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup to parse "https://openlibrary.org/".

I want to select all book in "popular books" section, so I try first select id="popular_carousel". And here is my code:

```
url="https://openlibrary.org/"

import urllib2

response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
source_code = response.read()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code)
# print soup.prettify()
vbpl=soup.select('#popular_carousel')
# print len(vbpl)
for itext in vbpl:
    print itext
```

But it's the result,nothing content in ul tag:

```
<ul class="homeCarousel jcarousel-skin-OL" id="popular_carousel">
</ul>
```

When I use css selector $('#popular_carousel')[0] I got the result:

```html
<ul class="homeCarousel jcarousel-list jcarousel-list-horizontal" id="popular_carousel" style="width: 5355px; left: 0px;"><li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-1 jcarousel-item-1-horizontal" jcarouselindex="1">
<div class="coverMagic">
  <span itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Book">
    <div class="SRPCover">
        <a href="/books/OL8053974M/Cat_in_an_Orange_Twist" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" title="Cat in an Orange Twist by Jean Little">
          <img itemprop="image" xsrc="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/6759233-M.jpg" src="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/6759233-M.jpg" alt="Cat in an Orange Twist" class="cover">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="coverEbook">
      <span class="actions read">
        <a href="/borrow/ia/catinorangetwist00doug" class="borrow-link" title="Read this book" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" data-key="/books/OL8053974M" data-ocaid="catinorangetwist00doug">
          <span class="read-icon image borrow"></span>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
</li><li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-2 jcarousel-item-2-horizontal" jcarouselindex="2">
<div class="coverMagic">
  <span itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Book">
    <div class="SRPCover">
        <a href="/books/OL1405697M/Without_remorse" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" title="Without remorse by Tom Clancy">
          <img itemprop="image" xsrc="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/7885550-M.jpg" src="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/7885550-M.jpg" alt="Without remorse" class="cover">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="coverEbook">
      <span class="actions read">
        <a href="/borrow/ia/withoutremorseclan00clan" class="borrow-link" title="Read this book" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" data-key="/books/OL1405697M" data-ocaid="withoutremorseclan00clan">
          <span class="read-icon image borrow"></span>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
</li><li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-3 jcarousel-item-3-horizontal" jcarouselindex="3">
<div class="coverMagic">
  <span itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Book">
    <div class="SRPCover">
        <a href="/books/OL972786M/The_cat_who_tailed_a_thief" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" title="The cat who tailed a thief by Jean Little">
          <img itemprop="image" xsrc="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/7890563-M.jpg" src="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/7890563-M.jpg" alt="The cat who tailed a thief" class="cover">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="coverEbook">
      <span class="actions read">
        <a href="/borrow/ia/catwhotailedthie00brau" class="borrow-link" title="Read this book" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" data-key="/books/OL972786M" data-ocaid="catwhotailedthie00brau">
          <span class="read-icon image borrow"></span>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
</li><li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-4 jcarousel-item-4-horizontal" jcarouselindex="4">
<div class="coverMagic">
  <span itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Book">
    <div class="SRPCover">
        <a href="/books/OL24935091M/The_Arizona_clan" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" title="The Arizona clan by Zane Grey">
          <img itemprop="image" xsrc="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/6978633-M.jpg" src="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/6978633-M.jpg" alt="The Arizona clan" class="cover">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="coverEbook">
      <span class="actions read">
        <a href="/borrow/ia/arizonaclan00grey" class="borrow-link" title="Read this book" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" data-key="/books/OL24935091M" data-ocaid="arizonaclan00grey">
          <span class="read-icon image borrow"></span>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
</li><li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-5 jcarousel-item-5-horizontal" jcarouselindex="5">
<div class="coverMagic">
  <span itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Book">
    <div class="SRPCover">
        <a href="/books/OL7728070M/Paths_less_travelled" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" title="Paths less travelled by ">
          <img itemprop="image" xsrc="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/7896665-M.jpg" src="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/7896665-M.jpg" alt="Paths less travelled" class="cover">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="coverEbook">
      <span class="actions read">
        <a href="/borrow/ia/pathslesstravell00bang" class="borrow-link" title="Read this book" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" data-key="/books/OL7728070M" data-ocaid="pathslesstravell00bang">
          <span class="read-icon image borrow"></span>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
</li><li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-6 jcarousel-item-6-horizontal" jcarouselindex="6">
<div class="coverMagic">
  <span itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Book">
    <div class="SRPCover">
        <a href="/books/OL21837057M/The_good_husband_of_Zebra_Drive" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" title="The good husband of Zebra Drive by Alexander McCall Smith">
          <img itemprop="image" xsrc="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/7254718-M.jpg" src="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/7254718-M.jpg" alt="The good husband of Zebra Drive" class="cover">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="coverEbook">
      <span class="actions read">
        <a href="/borrow/ia/goodhusbandofzeb00mcca_0" class="borrow-link" title="Read this book" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" data-key="/books/OL21837057M" data-ocaid="goodhusbandofzeb00mcca_0">
          <span class="read-icon image borrow"></span>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
</li><li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-7 jcarousel-item-7-horizontal" jcarouselindex="7">
<div class="coverMagic">
  <span itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Book">
    <div class="SRPCover">
        <a href="/books/OL24376409M/The_gossamer_cord" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" title="The gossamer cord by ">
          <img itemprop="image" xsrc="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/6623853-M.jpg" src="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/6623853-M.jpg" alt="The gossamer cord" class="cover">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="coverEbook">
      <span class="actions read">
        <a href="/borrow/ia/gossamercord00carr" class="borrow-link" title="Read this book" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" data-key="/books/OL24376409M" data-ocaid="gossamercord00carr">
          <span class="read-icon image borrow"></span>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
</li><li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-8 jcarousel-item-8-horizontal" jcarouselindex="8">
<div class="coverMagic">
  <span itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Book">
    <div class="SRPCover">
        <a href="/books/OL24206844M/The_far_side_of_the_dollar" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" title="The far side of the dollar by Ross Macdonald">
          <img itemprop="image" xsrc="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/6498853-M.jpg" src="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/6498853-M.jpg" alt="The far side of the dollar" class="cover">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="coverEbook">
      <span class="actions read">
        <a href="/borrow/ia/farsideofdollar00macd" class="borrow-link" title="Read this book" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" data-key="/books/OL24206844M" data-ocaid="farsideofdollar00macd">
          <span class="read-icon image borrow"></span>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
</li><li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-9 jcarousel-item-9-horizontal" jcarouselindex="9">
<div class="coverMagic">
  <span itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Book">
    <div class="SRPCover">
        <a href="/books/OL14443829M/Edge_of_evil" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" title="Edge of evil by J. A. Jance">
          <img itemprop="image" xsrc="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/6928404-M.jpg" src="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/6928404-M.jpg" alt="Edge of evil" class="cover">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="coverEbook">
      <span class="actions read">
        <a href="/borrow/ia/edgeofevil00janc" class="borrow-link" title="Read this book" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" data-key="/books/OL14443829M" data-ocaid="edgeofevil00janc">
          <span class="read-icon image borrow"></span>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
</li><li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-10 jcarousel-item-10-horizontal" jcarouselindex="10">
<div class="coverMagic">
  <span itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Book">
    <div class="SRPCover">
        <a href="/books/OL3665071M/Heaven_and_earth" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" title="Heaven and earth by ">
          <img itemprop="image" xsrc="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/319246-M.jpg" src="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/319246-M.jpg" alt="Heaven and earth" class="cover">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="coverEbook">
      <span class="actions read">
        <a href="/borrow/ia/heavenearth00robe" class="borrow-link" title="Read this book" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" data-key="/books/OL3665071M" data-ocaid="heavenearth00robe">
          <span class="read-icon image borrow"></span>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
</li><li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-11 jcarousel-item-11-horizontal" jcarouselindex="11">
<div class="coverMagic">
  <span itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Book">
    <div class="SRPCover">
        <a href="/books/OL23246927M/Purity_in_death" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" title="Purity in death by ">
          <img itemprop="image" xsrc="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/6640181-M.jpg" src="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/6640181-M.jpg" alt="Purity in death" class="cover">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="coverEbook">
      <span class="actions read">
        <a href="/borrow/ia/purityindeath00robb" class="borrow-link" title="Read this book" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" data-key="/books/OL23246927M" data-ocaid="purityindeath00robb">
          <span class="read-icon image borrow"></span>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
</li><li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-12 jcarousel-item-12-horizontal" jcarouselindex="12">
<div class="coverMagic">
  <span itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Book">
    <div class="SRPCover">
        <a href="/books/OL20944778M/50_Harbor_Street" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" title="50 Harbor Street by ">
          <img itemprop="image" xsrc="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/6955825-M.jpg" src="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/6955825-M.jpg" alt="50 Harbor Street" class="cover">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="coverEbook">
      <span class="actions read">
        <a href="/borrow/ia/50harborstreet00maco" class="borrow-link" title="Read this book" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" data-key="/books/OL20944778M" data-ocaid="50harborstreet00maco">
          <span class="read-icon image borrow"></span>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
</li><li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-13 jcarousel-item-13-horizontal" jcarouselindex="13">
<div class="coverMagic">
  <span itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Book">
    <div class="SRPCover">
        <a href="/books/OL24957544M/Blue_smoke" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" title="Blue smoke by ">
          <img itemprop="image" xsrc="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/6948813-M.jpg" src="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/6948813-M.jpg" alt="Blue smoke" class="cover">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="coverEbook">
      <span class="actions read">
        <a href="/borrow/ia/bluesmoke2006robe" class="borrow-link" title="Read this book" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" data-key="/books/OL24957544M" data-ocaid="bluesmoke2006robe">
          <span class="read-icon image borrow"></span>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
</li><li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-14 jcarousel-item-14-horizontal" jcarouselindex="14">
<div class="coverMagic">
  <span itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Book">
    <div class="SRPCover">
        <a href="/books/OL23246139M/Agatha_Raisin_and_the_love_from_hell" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" title="Agatha Raisin and the love from hell by M. C. Beaton">
          <img itemprop="image" xsrc="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/7097423-M.jpg" src="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/7097423-M.jpg" alt="Agatha Raisin and the love from hell" class="cover">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="coverEbook">
      <span class="actions read">
        <a href="/borrow/ia/agatharaisinlov00beat" class="borrow-link" title="Read this book" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" data-key="/books/OL23246139M" data-ocaid="agatharaisinlov00beat">
          <span class="read-icon image borrow"></span>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
</li><li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-15 jcarousel-item-15-horizontal" jcarouselindex="15">
<div class="coverMagic">
  <span itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Book">
    <div class="SRPCover">
        <a href="/books/OL23245311M/Uncommon_clay" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" title="Uncommon clay by MARGARET MARON">
          <img itemprop="image" xsrc="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/7013638-M.jpg" src="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/7013638-M.jpg" alt="Uncommon clay" class="cover">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="coverEbook">
      <span class="actions read">
        <a href="/borrow/ia/uncommonclay00maro" class="borrow-link" title="Read this book" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" data-key="/books/OL23245311M" data-ocaid="uncommonclay00maro">
          <span class="read-icon image borrow"></span>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
</li><li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-16 jcarousel-item-16-horizontal" jcarouselindex="16">
<div class="coverMagic">
  <span itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Book">
    <div class="SRPCover">
        <a href="/books/OL24217407M/The_prodigal_girl" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" title="The prodigal girl by Grace Livingston Hill Lutz">
          <img itemprop="image" xsrc="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/6554163-M.jpg" src="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/6554163-M.jpg" alt="The prodigal girl" class="cover">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="coverEbook">
      <span class="actions read">
        <a href="/borrow/ia/prodigalgirl00hill" class="borrow-link" title="Read this book" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" data-key="/books/OL24217407M" data-ocaid="prodigalgirl00hill">
          <span class="read-icon image borrow"></span>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
</li><li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-17 jcarousel-item-17-horizontal" jcarouselindex="17">
<div class="coverMagic">
  <span itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Book">
    <div class="SRPCover">
        <a href="/books/OL24382171M/An_unsuitable_job_for_a_woman" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" title="An unsuitable job for a woman by P. D. James">
          <img itemprop="image" xsrc="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/6633693-M.jpg" src="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/6633693-M.jpg" alt="An unsuitable job for a woman" class="cover">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="coverEbook">
      <span class="actions read">
        <a href="/borrow/ia/unsuitablejobfor00jame" class="borrow-link" title="Read this book" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" data-key="/books/OL24382171M" data-ocaid="unsuitablejobfor00jame">
          <span class="read-icon image borrow"></span>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
</li><li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-18 jcarousel-item-18-horizontal" jcarouselindex="18">
<div class="coverMagic">
  <span itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Book">
    <div class="SRPCover">
        <a href="/books/OL24216946M/Point_blank" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" title="Point blank by ">
          <img itemprop="image" xsrc="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/6552028-M.jpg" src="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/6552028-M.jpg" alt="Point blank" class="cover">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="coverEbook">
      <span class="actions read">
        <a href="/borrow/ia/pointblankfbithr00coul" class="borrow-link" title="Read this book" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" data-key="/books/OL24216946M" data-ocaid="pointblankfbithr00coul">
          <span class="read-icon image borrow"></span>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
</li><li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-19 jcarousel-item-19-horizontal" jcarouselindex="19">
<div class="coverMagic">
  <span itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Book">
    <div class="SRPCover">
        <a href="/books/OL23277794M/The_Darkest_Evening_of_the_Year" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" title="The Darkest Evening of the Year by ">
          <img itemprop="image" xsrc="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/6484429-M.jpg" src="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/6484429-M.jpg" alt="The Darkest Evening of the Year" class="cover">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="coverEbook">
      <span class="actions read">
        <a href="/borrow/ia/darkesteveningof00koon" class="borrow-link" title="Read this book" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" data-key="/books/OL23277794M" data-ocaid="darkesteveningof00koon">
          <span class="read-icon image borrow"></span>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
</li><li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-20 jcarousel-item-20-horizontal" jcarouselindex="20">
<div class="coverMagic">
  <span itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Book">
    <div class="SRPCover">
        <a href="/books/OL16412327M/Tell_no_one" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" title="Tell no one by Harlan Coben">
          <img itemprop="image" xsrc="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/5339304-M.jpg" src="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/5339304-M.jpg" alt="Tell no one" class="cover">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="coverEbook">
      <span class="actions read">
        <a href="/borrow/ia/tellnoone00cobe" class="borrow-link" title="Read this book" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" data-key="/books/OL16412327M" data-ocaid="tellnoone00cobe">
          <span class="read-icon image borrow"></span>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
</li><li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-21 jcarousel-item-21-horizontal" jcarouselindex="21">
<div class="coverMagic">
  <span itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Book">
    <div class="SRPCover">
        <a href="/books/OL3281849M/The_bachelor" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" title="The bachelor by ">
          <img itemprop="image" xsrc="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/6638799-M.jpg" src="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/6638799-M.jpg" alt="The bachelor" class="cover">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="coverEbook">
      <span class="actions read">
        <a href="/borrow/ia/bachelor00phil" class="borrow-link" title="Read this book" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" data-key="/books/OL3281849M" data-ocaid="bachelor00phil">
          <span class="read-icon image borrow"></span>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
</li><li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-22 jcarousel-item-22-horizontal" jcarouselindex="22">
<div class="coverMagic">
  <span itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/Book">
    <div class="SRPCover">
        <a href="/books/OL24744748M/Angel_trumpet" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" title="Angel trumpet by Ann McMillan">
          <img itemprop="image" xsrc="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/6798424-M.jpg" src="//covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/6798424-M.jpg" alt="Angel trumpet" class="cover">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="coverEbook">
      <span class="actions read">
        <a href="/borrow/ia/angeltrumpetcivi00mcmi" class="borrow-link" title="Read this book" data-ol-link-track="CarouselPopular" data-key="/books/OL24744748M" data-ocaid="angeltrumpetcivi00mcmi">
          <span class="read-icon image borrow"></span>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
</li>
```

Please help me to select that css selector.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use your developer tools when opening that website, on the `Network > XHR` tab, you'll see that it'll call at least two ajax methods that you want.

1) It'll call `https://openlibrary.org/popular?start=0&limit=100` to get some popular books (You can change start and limit).

2) After the first call is completed it'll call `https://openlibrary.org/api/editions?olids=%s&decoration=carousel_item&pixel=CarouselPopular` to get that book info. Notice that where  **`%s`** is you'll have to put the URLs of the books to get their data (Separated by commas).

Here is an example, I'll let you get the other book data (Available in the `book` node).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

POPULAR_BOOKS = requests.get("https://openlibrary.org/popular?start=0&limit=100")
AvailableBooksURL = [str(book[1]) for book in POPULAR_BOOKS.json()["books"]]
POPULAR_BOOKS_INFO = requests.get("https://openlibrary.org/api/editions?olids=%s&decoration=carousel_item&pixel=CarouselPopular" % ",".join(AvailableBooksURL))
BooksInfoHTML = "".join([book.encode("utf-8")for book in 
POPULAR_BOOKS_INFO.json()["books"]])

soup = BeautifulSoup(BooksInfoHTML, "html.parser")

for book in soup.find_all("div", class_="coverMagic hiddenCoverMagic"):
    print ("Title: %s" % book.div.a["title"])
```

Which will print:

```
Title: The Lord of the Rings The Return of the ... by J. R. R. Tolkien
Title: The Two Towers by J. R. R. Tolkien
Title: The fellowship of the ring by J. R. R. Tolkien
Title: Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone by J. K. Rowling
....
```